# Running a function in infinite loop on a different thread also executing the main thread. Python

Tags: python, multithreading, django-rest-framework, django-views, apscheduler

In a django app, I have a create() method, from viewset.

It is supposed to get some data, run a scrape function in an infinite loop using that data, also return a response while running that scrape function in the background.

Here is the code - create method:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        data = request.data.copy()
        response_data = {}
        response_data['requester_userid'] = request.user.id
        response_data['mail_addresses'] = data['mail_addresses']
        response_data['search_text'] = data['search_text']
        response_data['news_domain'] = data.getlist('news_domain[]')
        response_data['search_interval'] = data['search_interval']
        serializer = MailLinksSerializer(data=response_data)
        
        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.helper_for_automated_scrape_and_mail(response_data)
            # save the data to the db
            # serializer.save()
            # ?improvement: here an html page would be rendered as a response saying "Your request has been recorded and under processing. You will receive email shortly"
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

helper for my function that is called periodically

```
@background
    def helper_for_automated_scrape_and_mail(self,data):
        
        while True:
            self._automated_scrape_and_mail(data)
            time.sleep(int(data['search_interval']) * 60)
```

background decorator

```
 # A decorator to take the decorated function outside of the main function
def background(f):
    """
    a threading decorator use @background above the function that needs to run in the background
    """
    def background_func(*a,**kw):
        threading.Thread(target=f, args = a , kwargs = kw).start()
    return background_func
```

This way I run the scrape function in the background also return a response to the user.

My question is there a better and practical way to do achieve this instead of running an infinite while loop.

If I use appscheduler, how should I right this?